# JavaScript errors using <cfgrid> tag with ColdFusion 2018

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion, cfgrid

With ColdFusion 2018 using the `<cfgrid>` with the format set to "html".

```
<cfform action="" method="POST" name="TEST">
    <cfgrid name="test"  format="html">
            <CFGRIDCOLUMN NAME="A" HEADER="A" > 
            <CFGRIDCOLUMN NAME="B" HEADER="B" > 
    </cfgrid>
</cfform>
```

Running the above sample code on Chrome, I receive the following errors:

1. > https ://test-url/cf_scripts/scripts/ajax/**yui/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js**
   >       net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
2. > GET
   >   https ://test-url/cf_scripts/scripts/ajax/**yui/animation/animation-min.js**
   >   404 (Not Found)
3. > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
   >   **ext-all.js:18**
   >   `at i.getKey (ext-all.js:18)`
   >   `at i.add (ext-all.js:18)`
   >   `at c (ext-all.js:18)`
   >   `at i.onSelectChange (ext-all.js:18)`
   >   `at i.doMultiSelect (ext-all.js:18)`
   >   `at i.doSelect (ext-all.js:18)`
   >   `at i.select (ext-all.js:18)`
   >   **>`at $G.Actions.onLoad (cfgrid.js:490)`**
   >   `at b (ext-all.js:18)`

After looking into this I found that the YUI API used to come bundled  with ColdFusion has been [deprecated and removed](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/deprecated-features.html#main-pars_text_415665637) with Coldfusion 2016 update 3

According to the documentation only the following tags should be affected by the change ( Im guessing one of these is a dependency for `<CFGRID>`?)

- cfmenu
- cftree
- cftooptip
- cfcalendar
- cfinput (autosuggest attribute)
- cfinput (sourcefortooltip attribute)
- cfsprydataset

Without adding the depreciated API back into ColdFusion 2018... is there anyway to decouple YUI from the `<CFGRID>` tag as it behaves normally even with the error?

Can anything be done about the error from **ext-all.js** or is this a Coldfusion bug?

Comment: I bet it is a ColdFusion bug. It sounds like `<cfgrid>` is powered by YUI. No YUI, no `<cfgrid>`

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but out of curiosity, does the error go away if you download *only* those two javascript files from a CF2016 install?

Comment: I have only tried pulling the entire YUI, and the first two errors do go away. However the 3rd error from ext-all.js still persists. (Not too keen about pulling in the deprecated JS library tho .. as it is no longer maintained) ... The <cfgrid> still works even with the errors ... just a bit annoying having the errors printed to console

Comment: @Hedge7707 - Do you mean the 3rd error persists even after adding back the *whole* YUI library? i.e. Suggesting it's not related to YUI. *Edit* Could you post a small - standalone repro case?

Comment: @Ageax Yeah... it seems related to another JavaScript framework that CF uses  Ext JS (https://docs.sencha.com/ext/6.2.0/guides/quick_start/introduction.html)

Comment: @Hedge7707 - Never mind, missed the example ;-) Let me try it.

Comment: @Hedge7707 - Ugh.. yeah, I get the same 3 errors with CF2018, and the 1 error remains, even after copying in the whole YUI lib, so I'd say likely bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try Updating to the latest update of CF 2018  , update 5 , along with the YUI library in place. You might possibly skip all the above errors.

Only IE will still have a problem with error like this
*Unable to set property 'page' of undefined or null reference*